# React - Format input field to show currency using Dinero.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms

I'm building a form in react that has a few inputs that need to format with money currency. So it needs to prefix with the `$`, add commas, decimals (2 decimal point).

I found this library called `dinerojs.com`: https://dinerojs.com/ .

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it's not formatting. The field works how it is now, but with no formats. Any ideas?

```
//State
ProductPrice1: number,

//Set inital state
ProductPrice1: Dinero({ amount: 0 }).toFormat('$0,0.00'),

//handle bind
this.handleChangeProductPrice1  = this.handleChangeProductPrice1.bind(this);

//Change function
handleChangeProductPrice1y = async (event: any) => {
    const value = parseFloat(event.target.value)
    await this.setState({ ProductPrice1: value });      
}

//in my render
<input
    value={this.state.ProductPrice1}
    onChange={this.handleChangeProductPrice1}
    type="number"
    className="phone validate"
    name="ProductPrice1"                                        
/>
```

Comment: shouldn't you format the number again in the `handleChangeProductPrice1y` function?, also no need for async and await when setting the state

Comment: @ludwiguer can you post this as an answer so that if it works I can set it as the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do, leave the state without formatting and do the format in the render

```
//State
ProductPrice1: number,

//Set inital state
ProductPrice1: 0,

//handle bind
this.handleChangeProductPrice1  = this.handleChangeProductPrice1.bind(this);

//Change function
handleChangeProductPrice1y = (event: any) => {
    const value = parseFloat(event.target.value)
    this.setState({ ProductPrice1: value });      
}

//in my render
<input
    value={Dinero({ amount: this.state.ProductPrice1 }).toFormat('$0,0.00')}
    onChange={this.handleChangeProductPrice1}
    type="number"
    className="phone validate"
    name="ProductPrice1"                                        
/>
```

**EDIT**

You have 2 problems here:

1. You need to set the type of the input to text because if you use number it won't accept the formatting
2. I checked the Dinero docs and there is no way to convert an amount already formatted to number again, so parseFloat won't work, I think you need to look for another library like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-currency-input

**EDIT 2**

Maybe you can make it work replacing the characters (`$`, `,` and `.`) so you keep only the numbers like this

```
  handleChangeProductPrice = (event: any) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const number = value.replace(/\$|,|\./g, "");
    setProductPrice(parseInt(number, 10));
  };
```

Comment: it wont even load the application

Comment: ah I see, any suggestions? Thank you btw,

Comment: i was using that one before actually! the reason I switched is because that react-currency-input isn't supported with Edge browser and i need it to be

Comment: @hisusu32 I edited the answer, maybe that can help you

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
<input
    value={this.state.ProductPrice1}
    onChange={(event) => this.setState({ ProductPrice1: Dinero({ amount: event.target.value }).toFormat('$0,0.00') })}
    type="number"
    className="phone validate"
    name="ProductPrice1"                                        
/>
```

should work.

Hop this helps.

Comment: This doesn't even allow me to enter any characters in the input anymore. Not sure why